# Fullcalendar (v5) Angular not implementing event backgroundColor in dayGridMonth view

Tags: angular, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

When setting the color/backgroundColor of an event it works great in the views "timeGridDay" and "timeGridWeek",

but does not seem to affect the events in "dayGridMonth" view (despite the events having that property).

timeGridWeek:

[image]

[image]

dayGridMonth:

[image]

[image]

Anyone has any idea why or what's a workaround (without going into the native elements and manipulating the css) ?

Comment: by default, timed events in the month view are shown without any background or borders (as you can see in the demos on the fullCalendar home page). But you can change that - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventDisplay . If you change it to block view, the background should apply.

Comment: Thanks @ADyson ! That solved it!